# How to fix error "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python." when trying to install pyqt5-tools using pip?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to install pyqt5-tools using pip and could not install it due to some error. I'm using Python 3.10.1 and the pip version is 21.3.1

The installation code that I wrote was

`pip install pyqt5-tools`

and the error was

```
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.3
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\Python\python.exe' 'D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph2s35v4n'
       cwd: C:\Users\amanm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q05mh73e\pyqt5_3649dffcf5fa408ebca8be299a9359ee
  Complete output (29 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
  AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
```

Comment: PyQt is not yet available for Python 3.10, use 3.9.

Comment: Ohh Okay, thanks. I will try it with 3.9 version.